# nao consigo usar :checked

Tags: css, css3, checkbox, menu

```css
css: .menu {
  display: block;
}


/* CSS quando o checkbox está marcado */

#bt-menu:checked~.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bt_menu">
  <label for="bt_menu"></label>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Serviços</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">criação de sites</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">arte visual</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">cursos</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">java</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">photoshop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">criação de sites</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">contatos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

no caso eu clico para sumir e nada acontece, continua como se fosse display:block

Comment: Ursula, o seletor *CSS* `~` é utilizado para encontrar irmãos de um elemento. Em uma hierarquia de arvores ser nós irmãos significa significa possuírem o mesmo nó como pai ou seja devem estar no mesmo nível. No seu exemplo `#bt-menu` é filho de `<div class="menuu">` enquanto `.menu` é filho de outro `<div>`.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 3):

Motivos de não estar funcionando:

- seu input tem o ID "bt_menu" mas no CSS está "bt-menu";
- para usar o sibling combinator ("~"), o input deve estar num nível que tenha acesso aos elementos que você queira controlar. E, no caso, ele está travado dentro da div "menuu", então o selector não funciona para nada fora dela;
- também é necessário incluir o * no selector:

```
#bt_menu:checked ~ * .menu
```

Segue abaixo exemplo funcional com algumas modificações:

- Movi o checkbox para o nível mais alto, dessa forma ela tem acesso a todos os outros elementos;
- Criei uma classe "escondivel". Tudo que usar ela será escondido. Achei que fazia mais sentido.

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
}

#escondido:checked ~ * .escondivel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="escondido">

<div class="menuu">
  <label for="escondido" id="btn-esconder">esconder</label>
</div>
<div>
  <nav class="menu escondivel">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Serviços</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">criação de sites</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">arte visual</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">cursos</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">java</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">photoshop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">criação de sites</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">contatos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```